# Magnifier not magnifying CSS/ JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my magnifier set up. Take a look.
http://www.omarhabash.com/twyla[image]

Looks like all works except it is not magnifying... Can some one tell me exactly what I am missing to magnify the image in the magnifier cursor?

Comment: Please post the code you want to look at here instead of directing people to debug code on an external website.

Comment: if you don't initialize library anywhere and have a bug in code (reference error for some 'google' object) so why are you surprised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap's "magnify" plugin.

Its [docs](https://github.com/marcaube/bootstrap-magnify) say "If you want to show the large preview at a 200% ratio, just use an image twice the size of its container."  In your website, you are already displaying the image at its full size, which is why the "magnified" version is identical to the original.

Just use a larger image and in the html set its size to the same pixel dimensions you currently have; the plugin will do the rest for you.

Comment: wow... I spent too long looking for some kind of catastrophic failure when it was actually simple. Thanks!

Comment: So I did what you said... Now I realized that the ghosted full size image is what is being magnified. [for example] when I try to magnify the eye — I am actually magnifying the part of the image that would be there if i did not shrink it... Take a look http://omarhabash.com/twyla/